# What might be the reason for improper turn on of IGBT

Tags: boost, converter, failure, igbt

[image: Traces][image: Upper-Vge at IGBT leg, Lower-Current through IGBT]Here I am applying 3-phase rectified dc to the non-isolated boost converter, the magnitude of applied voltage is 450V and desired o/p voltage is 475V. Switching frequency of PWM is 28k. I am using TC4420 driver IC to drive the IGBT (IKW40N123H3). But when I am starting PWM circuit IGBT's temperature is increasing at a very high rate and this causing igbt failure. I have captured gate to emitter waveform and collector to emitter waveform and I found that collector to emitter waveform is not right. Its voltage is not approaching to zero when GATE PULSE is high. What might be the reason for such a collector-emitter waveform? [image][image][image]

Comment: I have found IGBT's to be very sensitive to ground bounce. Source must have a low resistance ground return to power source. Usually 10 to 12 volts will saturate the IGBT ON. Less than 10 volts but > 3V is in the linear region and it will get HOT! Do you have it mounted to a heatsink? You should.

Comment: Yes, I am using heatsinkand it is also getting very hot. I didn't understood  yoursecond  sentense (Source must have a low resistance ground return to power source)

Comment: @Vick. I mean the IGBT source lead must use heavy gauge wire or wide-thick trace back to power source

Comment: Yes, thickness of trace is proper. I need opinion about Gate pulse too. Is it appropriate?

Comment: Please show detailed Vge and Vce oscillograms, along with Vcc for your gate driver.

Comment: Show photo of your wiring, including the gate-driver.

Comment: @winny I have two channel oscilloscope so i can capture two w/f at a time and as per your advise, I have observed the VCC of the gate driver and it is stable 15V.

Comment: Please show so. In general, develiping high powered electronics with a two channel scope is doomed to cause problems. Also, show layout.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf For security reasons I cannot upload whole ckt diagram

Comment: @winny layout is not possible.

Comment: Understandable. But we still need Vge and Vce oscillogram.

Comment: @winny, Vge and Vce waveforms are added in question.

Comment: @Vck Your IGBT isn't turning off either. You should be seeing the Collector fly-up after turn-off. What does the VDC supply look like?

Comment: @winny I have added gate-emitter waveform. The shape of this waveform is not looking good. I have observed that PWM at an output of driver IC is clean but at gate-emitter terminal it's shape is totally changed. Is it due to the layout?

Comment: @vck Most probably. I understand your struggle if you can't share company proprietary information, but could you sketch how it looks, which layers you are using and what distances and trace widths we are talking about?

Comment: @winny I have added picture which can give little information about routing. Please refer posted circuit diagram along with it. Note- Thickness of PCB is 2.5mm

Comment: Oh! minibloc. :-( If you add up the delay, rise and fall times of the device, it's about 450 ns, so your ~900 ns on-time will be just about only switching losses. If you move your scope to your Vge pins, you will see the ground jump and all gate impedance on top of that, so I'm not sure you have anything left. Can you float your scope or use diff probe and place local ground at the collector and measure actual gate on one channel and gate driver output on the other?

Comment: How much power are you looking at transfering? Have you considered interleaving several boost converters with smaller and better IGBTs instead, to facitiltate the layout? Price could even be lower...

Comment: @winny this is someone else's handover to me. So I need to carryforward it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85186/discussion-between-winny-and-vck).

Comment: @sstobbe yes. It is not properly turning off

Answer (score 2):

To avoid damage from Ground Bounce, as noted by Sparky256, plan your wiring like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1DQce.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @winny I have added waveform of driver IC supply during switching. It seems ok.

Comment: connection from driver IC to gate-emitter of IGBT is in same manner as shown in your picture.

Comment: What about magnetic coupling from the high-slew-rate current into the gate-control loop? Or coupling via electric-fields? How close is the Gate wiring to the collector wiring?

Comment: There is a TRANSFORMER in the emitter. Thus your wiring cannot be as I drew in the answer.

Comment: Gate trace is 5mm apart from collector trace.

Comment: current transformer is used there to sense the current.

Comment: What is the rate-of-change-of-current?